# How to import a c++ lib(x64) using QT creator 7 in windows 10

Tags: qt

I follow the steps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ4NAHHr41I to add a prebuild(vs 2015) dynamic lib BuildTestLib.lib using qt creator 7

I can use class(member variable) and variable in BuildTestLib.h, but got build error when I called any function.

---

```
ui->pushButton->setText("test");

//enum from BuildTestLib.lib
RAD_WMK_ERROR error;
// class from BuildTestLib.lib
CBuildTestLib *handle;

// function from BuildTestLib.lib
//handle = CreatInstance(RAD_I2C, VENDOR_QUALCOMM, &error);  

// function from BuildTestLib.lib
uint64_t test = fnBuildTestLib();
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        handle->gamma_data_10bit[i * 15 + j] = j + (i%10)*100;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4320; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        handle->position_data_8bit[i * 16 + j] = j + (i % 10) * 16;
    }
}

// a member function of CBuildTestLib from BuildTestLib.lib
//handle->dbg_save_all_data();
```

---

:-1: error: release/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `__imp__Z14fnBuildTestLibv'

:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

did I miss something? any suggestion?  thx

Note: this lib has been checked by vs 2015 c++ console application, and it works.

---

win32: LIBS += -L'D:/Kevin.Lai/vs2015/BuildTestLib/x64/Release/' -lBuildTestLib

INCLUDEPATH += 'D:/Kevin.Lai/vs2015/BuildTestLib/BuildTestLib'

DEPENDPATH += 'D:/Kevin.Lai/vs2015/BuildTestLib/BuildTestLib'

---

hope this information helps

Comment: The collect2 error usually occurs when you have not linked the library

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the lib, header, and the DLL in the same folder.

```
Set
win32: LIBS += -L'D:/Kevin.Lai/vs2015/BuildTestLib/x64/Release/' -lBuildTestLib

INCLUDEPATH += 'D:/Kevin.Lai/vs2015/BuildTestLib/x64/Release'

DEPENDPATH += 'D:/Kevin.Lai/vs2015/BuildTestLib/x64/Release'
```

That’s really odd.